# meteor app: images not loading

Tags: html, image, meteor

I'm making a simple chat app with meteor. My HTML is:

```
<body>
    <h1 align="center">tomomi-chat</h1>
    <img src="original.gif">
    <div class="container" align="center">
    {{>entryfield}}
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="container">
    {{>messages}}
    </div>
```

The image won't load on the local server. As the app is extremely simplistic, there are no folders besides the '.meteor' folder in the directory. The .js, .css, and .html files are all in the app directory.

Even if I host the image and use an external link, the result in the same. Why is meteor blocking images from my app?

deployed: http://tomomi.meteor.com/

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should create a folder named **public** in your application root folder.

From the [Meteor documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/filestructure):

> **/public**
>
> Files in /public are served to the client as-is. Use this to
> store assets such as images. For example, if you have an image located
> at /public/background.png, you can include it in your HTML with  or in your CSS with background-image:
> url(/background.png). Note that /public is not part of the image URL.

Answer (score 5):

To elaborate on this, I would add images asset directory in the public folder like this and serve it via like this

`images/transparent.jpg`

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Create a `/public` folder. put your images there.

Answer (score 2):

Put assets in **PROJECT/public** folder and when you specify link in tag, just use "**xyz.jpg**".

**Thats it!** The URL does not include **/public** folder in it. It is very very taken correctly by meteor framework.

**CORRECT ->** "xyz.jpg"

**INCORRECT ->** "/public/xyz.jpg"

Answer (score 0):

If you are Windows 10 user make public folder like that and call it in simple way

[image]

[image]