# The HTMLImageElement provided is in the 'broken' state

Tags: image, canvas, meteor

so i've been trying to load some images to a meteor project, on the onRendered function that also includes lots of other stuff that were indeed rendered.

```
Template.Canvas.onRendered(function() {
    this.blues = new Image();
    this.blues.src = "bluesh.png";
}
```

then in an autorun function that also includes some other things, there's

```
this.ctx.drawImage(this.blues, this.dotsPaint[i].xCntr - this.radius, this.dotsPaint[i].yCntr - this.radius, this.radius * 2, this.radius * 2);
```

when launching and triggering the painting code, i got this error:

> **Console Error:** failed to execute drawimage on canvasrenderingcontext2d the
>   htmlimageelement provided is in the broken state.

i read some online and seen advices to use onload functions for images, so i've done

```
this.blues = new Image();
this.blues.src = "bluesh.png";

    this.blues.onload = function () {
        this.imageLoadCheck++;
        console.log("test");
    };
```

the onload function was never triggered.
the image file is placed in the same folder as the file that uses it
project/imports/game
i also tried placing the images at the same folder of main.js which imports the canvas code, that didn't work either. also tried placing in different folders and changing to /..images/bluesh.png, i tried placing the image code on template.Canvas.onCreated instead of onRendered, nothing worked.
is there a different way of loading images on meteor? am i missing something?

thanks!

edit: here's the full console error:

```
Exception from Tracker recompute function:
debug.js:41 Error: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The HTMLImageElement provided is in the 'broken' state.
    at Error (native)
    at .<anonymous> (localhost:3000/app/app.js?hash=f237cc69921b50eb7ae7894d886737d7ca6557f8:272:18)
    at localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=ef41aed769a8945fc99ac4954e8c9ec157a88cea:1875:20
    at Function.Template._withTemplateInstanceFunc (localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=ef41aed769a8945fc99ac4954e8c9ec157a88cea:3687:12)
    at localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=ef41aed769a8945fc99ac4954e8c9ec157a88cea:1873:29
    at Object.Blaze._withCurrentView (localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=ef41aed769a8945fc99ac4954e8c9ec157a88cea:2214:12)
    at viewAutorun (localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=ef41aed769a8945fc99ac4954e8c9ec157a88cea:1872:18)
    at Tracker.Computation._compute (localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?hash=b605200c15f3a57abb701c7cbc58ca5b0f2802d7:351:36)
    at Tracker.Computation._recompute (localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?hash=b605200c15f3a57abb701c7cbc58ca5b0f2802d7:370:14)
    at Object.Tracker._runFlush (localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?hash=b605200c15f3a57abb701c7cbc58ca5b0f2802d7:535:14)
```

Comment: the error i pasted was from the F12, no misspells either. tried posting the pic from the html and got a blank photo spot with out the pic in it.

Comment: Does the onerror or onabort trigger? There is btw an error in the handler where it increments the undefined imageLoadCheck. Drawing to canvas must also happen after the onload has triggered. If you get this error and you say onload isn't triggered it would seem that drawImage happens outside the handler...? Could be that the image only gets partially loaded.

Comment: this is the full f12 report:

Comment: empty report? Also check the network tab to see if it loads the image at all and what return code you get.

Comment: sry, new to stackoverflow, i edited my initial post

Comment: also, in network it has all the pics on the list but for all of them it says "failed to load response data"

Comment: Rememeber that `this` context may change depending on how you call it, f.ex. inside the load handler this references the image, not the original context anymore. You can bind the current this to the handler, or reference the original this inside the handler by first storing it to a variable, f.ex: `var me = this; img.onload = function() { me.method() /* me=original this */ }; or: ` img.onload = handler.bind(this);`.

Comment: Is this in Chrome btw?

Comment: ye this was incorrect, but i changed it into an arrow function now which should make it correct and still it doesn't solve anything nor enters the onload function. and yes its chrome

Comment: btw i just read that pics in meteor are usually stored in a "public" folder, is this mendatory? though i just created one and placed the pics there too and still doesn't work..

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27353568/meteor-app-images-not-loading) may help with the public/ folder and possibly the path name.

Comment: alright, placed the pics in public and referred to them as "/bluesh.png" and such, and it worked. thx for the help!